# Points in Express Entry would automatically be deducted if person ages while waiting in the pool?

Tags: visa, canada, express-entry

applied 6 months back to Express Entry. But since waiting in the pool and the fact Canada IRCC had halted Express Entry due to pandemic, my age got higher. Now once the Express entry pool open, will the 5 points automatically deducted from my profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determining score for invitation is calculated on the day of each round of invitations.

The determining score, and most other relevant legal requirements, for assessing an application is [the day when the application for permanent residence is *submitted*](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/permanent-residence/express-entry/assessing-electronic-application-on-section-a11-2.html).

However, there is a [public policy exemption](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/mandate/policies-operational-instructions-agreements/age-based-requirements.html) in place to "protect" your score and eligibility based on your age on the date of invitation. **You do not benefit from the protection until you receive an invitation to apply.**

Time-limited factors other than the age can still cause your application to fail. For example, your language scores are only valid for two years, and they must be valid on the day when you submit the application for permanent residence to obtain the language points. If your score becomes lower than the lowest CRS points required for that round of invitation, your application will be refused.

Comment: so assuming that my IELTS is still valid but my age has increase, so next year the points for age that I got last year will still be valid? Inother words not decreased?

Comment: What is "The determining score for invitation is calculated on the day of each round of invitations." Are you talking about CRS cutoff?

Comment: @user0193 If you have got an ITA, then it is the age on the date you receive ITA that matters. If you have not been issued an ITA, then it will be determined on the day when a round of invitations is announced. CRS cutoff is specific to each round of invitations.